# Data structure for large geographical based coordinates?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, coordinate

I don't really care about the language used.

I have a large database of around 84.1k entries for various aeronautical coordinates around the world, they are formatted like this:

```
A1 023 UBL 15.245197 104.865917
A1 024 BUTRA 15.418278 105.596083
A1 025 PAPRA 15.766667 107.183333
A1 026 BATEM 15.931389 107.765556
A1 027 DAN 16.052778 108.198333
A1 028 BUNTA 16.833334 109.395000
A1 029 LENKO 17.416667 110.300000
A1 030 IKELA 18.661667 112.245000
A1 031 IDOSI 19.000000 112.500000
A1 032 CH 22.219542 114.030056
```

The first number is the air route (there are hundreds of these). The second number is the position the coordinate holds in terms of the air route sequence. The third is the name of the fix, 4th and 5th are the coordinates themselves.

A better way to describe it would be a highway. Let's say the A1 is a highway. UBL, BUTRA, PAPRA, etc... are all the exits. 023, 024, 025 is the order that you will encounter these exits (I will see UBL after 22 exits, as it is the 23rd then BUTRA, 24 then PAPRA, 25).

However, those exits lead to new highways rather than cities. For example, the UBL exit leads  onto

```
A1 023 UBL 15.245197 104.865917
G473 006 UBL 15.245197 104.865917
R470 001 UBL 15.245197 104.865917
W1 018 UBL 15.245197 104.865917
W4 031 UBL 15.245197 104.865917
W5 013 UBL 15.245197 104.865917
```

My ultimate goal is to, using these points, find the shortest distance in between 2 cities, using these air routes. However, That is not my problem. I can figure out that, but I'm not sure of which structure to use to hold this thing. It was my programming teacher who first suggested that I'll need some sort of structure to organize the data.

I'm thinking.. since I'm going to have the first and last points available, to search through the list, grab all the possible "highways" that that point leads into, use something like A* to find the shortest path, and restrict the number of branches by using some distance restrictions. However, as said, I was left unclear of which data structure to use.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you use a graph as the data structure? You could also maybe use the physical coordinates as part of the search heuristic if you use A*.

Comment: 84k entries is not really much for a database. For a search, maybe, but from the storage point of view, not.

Comment: Have you considered one of the no-sql databases already? A graph one, maybe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_Database

Answer (score 0):

You should use a spatial data structure like the [PM1 Quadtree](http://donar.umiacs.umd.edu/quadtree/lines/pm1.html).

You should also evaluate it against the [PM2 Quadtree](http://donar.umiacs.umd.edu/quadtree/lines/pm2.html) and [PM3 Quadtree](http://donar.umiacs.umd.edu/quadtree/lines/pm3.html) to see which one fits better for your constraints.